# Drill a hole {in/into/in to/to} the ground

Tags: prepositions

Can you tell me which one is correct?

> these shafts are made by drilling a hole in to the ground....

or,

> in the ground
>   into the ground
>   to the ground

which one?

Comment: This might be useful: https://writingexplained.org/into-vs-in-to-difference

Comment: Why does your title ask which are true but your question asks which are correct? These are completely different things!!! **True never means correct in English.**

Comment: I think you might need this: https://research.engineering.ucdavis.edu/gpa/foundations-deep/drilled-shaft-construction-2/ We drills holes in the ground, in English.

Answer (score 1):

I found an example in OLAD, which seems works here,
The bomb blew **a hole in the ground**. 
according to this example, your sentence should be :
these shafts are made by drilling **a hole in the ground**.